# How can I disable multiple links with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<a title="Login" data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login" 
   data-title="Admin" data-entity="n/a" 
   id="loginLink" class="nav-button dialogLink"><b>Login</b></a>

<a title="Register" 
   data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Register" 
   data-title="Admin" data-entity="n/a"
   id="registerLink" class="nav-button dialogLink"><b>Register</b></a>
```

When a user clicks on the #loginLink or #registerLink I would like 
to disable the link and call a dialog script. I created the following 
function:

```
$("#loginLink, #registerLink")
    .click(function () {
        $('#loginLink').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#registerLink').prop('disabled', true);
        dialog(this);
    });
```

It calls the dialog correctly but doesn't disable the links and if I 
click the buttons more than once it calls up more than one dialog
box. Is there something I am doing wrong? I can't see why it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind and unbind events at any time, store the code in a function, then you can use namespaced events to associate the event with that function.

```
function dlog(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dialog(this);
}

var $els = $("#loginLink, #registerLink");

$els.on('click.dlog', function(e){ dlog(e) }); // bind
$els.off('.dlog'); // unbind
```

**Edit:**
Another option would be to use `one()` which attaches the event just once, then you can attach the event again when the dialog is closed.

```
$els
  .one(function(e) { dlog(e) })
  .dialog({
     beforeClose: function() { 
       $els.one(function(e) { dlog(e) });
     }
  });
```

Comment: @clclanrs - Is your syntax right. Sorry I just didn't see like this before. I am not sure I understand the function parameters you set up for bind and unbind. What do you mean with 'click.dlog' and '.dlog' ?

Comment: Those are namespaced events. You can read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `dlog` is short for "dialog", you can use whatever you want as namespace.

Comment: Can you give an example. Sorry but I still can't understand what you mean with the function parameters after $els.on( and $els.off( but I understand how the dlog function works. Can you make it like the other suggestion. Thank you. SOrry I am asking a lot of questins

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand the function parameters after $els.on( and $els.off( what does it mean with 'click.dlog' and '.dlog'. I realize your code is very concise but can you make it more verbose so I can follow it. You mention $.els.dialog but this doesn't exist in my application. dialog is a function I use to open a modal window for login. There's no beforeClose set up. Do I have to set one of those up also?

Comment: I thought you were using jQuery UI for the dialog... For the confusing `click.dlog` syntax read about **namespaced events** in the jQuery Docs for `on()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery's `on()` and `off()` methods to bind/unbind events. Setting `disabled` property have no effects on links, click events will still be fired.

Here you can find a description and demo:
http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: If OP uses on / off (jQuery 1.7 or later required), bind / unbind or delegate / undelegate does not matter. OP does not have to use on/off but any off the methods will do as long as the event is unbound or prevented from propagating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
$("#loginLink, #registerLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dialog(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#loginLink, #registerLink").on("click", function () {
 dialog(this);
 return false;
});
```

`return false` in jQuery will execute both, `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` where second one will prevent event from bubbling up and that's what you are after.

additional info:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)